# disable lightbox in a plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, css, theme-customizer

i'm using the [PHOTO ALBUM plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-gallery/) for wordpress and I would like to disable the lighbox effects - meaning, i just want to show the thumbnails...

is that even possible?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to determine the handle of the script that they are enqueueing, and you can [dequeue it yourself](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) and prevent it from being loaded. I downloaded the plugin and had a look, my guess is (I haven't tested) that the lightbox script is jquery.fullscreen-0.4.1.js, which gets loaded on line 2448 of photo-gallery.php

```
function my_lightbox_prevention() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-fullscreen' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-fullscreen' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_lightbox_prevention', 100 );
```

Add that to functions.php and it should do the trick. You might have to dequeue a couple other scripts as well but this should point you in the right direction at the very least.